# Setup Spyder to work with Anaconda python on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, spyder

I installed Spyder IDE before I have installed the Anaconda (on Ubuntu 14.04), on the terminal when I type `python` I have the anaconda python and I can import all of its packages. But on Spyder I still have the original python and I cannot import the Anaconda packages, how can I setup Spyder to use the Anaconda python?

Comment: If I enter to the anaconda path and type spyder the spyder does start up with the anaconda python environment..

Comment: please also tell us your operating system

Comment: have you tried setting the Python executable in `Tools->Preferences->Console->Advanced Settings`?

Comment: Where can I find the Python executable that Anaconda runs?

Comment: you can try `which -a python` if anaconda's python is already in your path. Otherwise have a look in your home directory. I guess it's in `~/anaconda/` or similar.

Comment: You have two Spyder modules actually: one is located with the modules of the old Python installation, and another with Anaconda Python (should be under lib\site-packages\spyderlib). You should also find a shell script to execute this last one, under the "scripts" directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution here is to use the Spyder that comes with Anaconda.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep your older version as well as the anaconda version python too. Install Anaconda python as root user. Then install spyder as root too. Then Running spyder as root will allow you to use Anaconda version Python and running spyder in home user will let you use older version of python. You can refer my blog for the same [Blog](http://spachori.blogspot.com/)